# How to rotate labels in clustered bar charts

Tags: labeling, charts, rotation

I can label groups in a bar chart but when trying to rotate the column labels I get unexpected results.

This works:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
 ChartLabels -> {{"c1", "c2"}, {"r1", "r2", "r3"}}]
```

this doesn't:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[{{"c1", "c2"}, {"r1", "r2", "r3"}}, Axis, Rotate[#, Pi/4] &]]
```

What am I doing wring?

Comment: `BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
 ChartLabels -> 
  Map[Rotate[#, Pi/4] &, {{"c1", "c2"}, {"r1", "r2", "r3"}}, {2}]]`

Comment: `ChartLabels -> (Placed[#, Axis, Rotate[#, Pi/4] &] & /@ {{"c1", 
     "c2"}, {"r1", "r2", "r3"}})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Placed` should be inside the `List`:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"c1", "c2"}, Axis, Rotate[#, Pi/4] &], 
    Placed[{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, Axis, Rotate[#, Pi/4] &]}]
```

[image]